# SharePoint 2019 configuration wizard error

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, configuration-wizard

I am installing SharePoint 2019 on 3 separate servers

1. Active directory
2. SQL server
3. SharePoint server.

at first I config active directory and then join my SQL server and SharePoint server to active directory domain. my SQL install successfully and SharePoint install successfully too, but when I want config my SharePoint, in specify configuration Database setting I got ERROR.
database server: computer name of SQL server
database name: default
username: domain\user
[image]

please help me, what I am wrong?

Comment: try to ping 'sql' or open shared folder from SP server. What is the result?

Answer (score 3):

This issue usually occurs in case of:

The Database Server is not reachable from the SharePoint Application Server.

The SQL Server port is closed and is not accessible from SharePoint Application Server.

Please check [How to Check SQL Server Instance Connectivity from the application server to database server for a specific user](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/28/check-sql-server-instance-connectivity/).

SQL Server Service is stopped.

SQL Agent is stopped.

SQL Server Browser is stopped.

SQL Server Network Configuration TCP/IP is disabled.

SQL Server server was blocked by Firewall.
The provided account doesn’t have sufficient permission.

Please check [Can not connect to database master at SQL server in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/01/29/cannot-connect-to-database-master-at-sql-server-at-servername-the-database-might-not-exist-or-the-current-user-does-not-have-permission-to-connect/)

Answer (score 2):

from the error, it is giving the hint that their is problem with SQL server connection from your SharePoint server. Couple of things to check.

- Make sure their is no firewall block between SharePoint and SQL
- Make sure port 1433 is not blocked by any software or firewall.
- All the required SQL services are up and running on SQL server
- Account you using to connect SQL should have the right permission (DB creator and Security Admin)
- server is ping-able and accessible over the network.
- also reboot the server if you make any changes on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Check have you completed your ADDS controller and verify your SQL Server name  username Domain\Username enter properly.